# Is it possible to use WordPress theme preview as main website source that will work all functions?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm new in WordPress
I misunderstand one thing about the theme use in WordPress

For example, I wanna create the as same website as [this](https://preview.themeforest.net/item/poco-fast-food-restaurant-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/28465454?_ga=2.123768782.534066798.1612368522-1561752006.1612368522) I purchased this template.

But when I installed the theme in WordPress it shows me the default Index.php file with little info, used my purchased theme

And when I purchased the theme there exist all src files of the above website.

How I can use my purchased src files of website that will work all function for ex: logins with db?

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you purchased the theme, you probably have just installed the theme and haven't created any pages or tweaked any settings. So if you want to get the same look as that of the preview website, you probably have to check whether the developer has provided any dummy data for importing.

Most of the themes listed in ThemeForest would have the option to import dummy data, so that customers would be able to install some pre-made posts, pages, config, etc. This might be there inside the custom settings page(as a single button to download the content) of the theme, or maybe they have provided it in separate XML files for you to import. If the files you have downloaded doesn't have it, make sure you downloaded **All files & documentation**. Here's a sample screenshot:

[image]

My guess is that you might have only downloaded using the **Installable WordPress file only** option.

If you are still unable to get the dummy data, probably you have to ping the support of that theme asking them to provide the dummy data.